# Image Rollover not working

Tags: java, image, swing

Can anyone help me with the code please. I have two images `1.jpg` and `2.jpg`, when i run the program ,`1.jpg` appears on button, but when i hover the mouse on button, `2.jpg` does not appear. Below is the code, Thanks

```
import javax.swing.*;

class ButtonRollover {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String path1 = ("C:\\1.jpg");
    String path2 = ("C:\\2.jpg");

    final JLabel pic1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(path1));
    final JLabel pic2 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(path2));

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {


             JButton button = new JButton("Hover");
             button.setRolloverIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\2.jpg"));
             button.add(pic1);
             button.setRolloverEnabled(true);

             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, button);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not supposed to add a label inside a button. Just set its icon with

```
button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(path1));
```

instead of

```
button.add(pic1);
```